# С++. Класс. Как называется конструкция foo::foo и зачем она нужна?

Tags: c++, классы, g++

Я новичок в С++, и приходится писать на этом непонятном языке. Нам нужно создать класс, и в методе `main` выполнить его методы. Когда я создал класс, он не определился в `main`, по этому решил попробовать стандартный код класса в редакторе. Но тут *vs code* нам предлагает конструкцию `foo::foo`. Что такое `foo::foo`, и зачем она нужна ?

```
class foo
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    foo(/* args */);
    ~foo();
};

foo::foo(/* args */)
{
}

foo::~foo()
{
}
```

Comment: конструктор это foo::foo(/* args */). Специальный метод для создания и инициализации объекта

Comment: foo::~foo деструктор

Comment: [классы C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes)

Comment: Извините, тогда получается у нас 2 конструктора ? foo() и foo::foo()?

Comment: конструкторов может быть сколько угодно

Comment: foo() и foo::foo() первый это вызов а второй обьявление

Comment: Ок. Спасибо большое) Я всегда думал что конструктор в с++ это foo() или foo(const string a) : a(a) {}. А тут на тебе, foo:: foo()

Comment: тот что в классе `foo(/* args */);` это объявление конструктора (функции), `foo::foo(/* args */)
{
}` - определение конструктора (функции). Загуглите объявление и определение методов и функций

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Конструктор](https://ravesli.com/urok-116-konstruktory/) — это особый тип метода класса, который автоматически вызывается при создании объекта этого же класса. Конструкторы обычно используются для инициализации переменных-членов класса значениями, которые предоставлены по умолчанию/пользователем, или для выполнения любых шагов настройки, необходимых для используемого класса

В отличие от обычных методов, конструкторы имеют определенные правила их именования:

- конструкторы всегда должны иметь то же имя, что и класс (учитываются
  верхний и нижний регистры);
- конструкторы не имеют типа возврата (даже void).

Обратите внимание, конструкторы предназначены только для выполнения инициализации. Не следует пытаться вызывать конструктор для повторной инициализации существующего объекта. Хотя это может скомпилироваться без ошибок, результаты могут получиться неожиданные (компилятор создаст временный объект, а затем удалит его).